# Crystal Sub Report gets repeated in Details Section

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Did anyone found the solution to this problem?? Subreport inside Details section gets repeated. 
[image]

[image]

Is there a way to display subreport only once? I don't want to put it in header. 
Please help guys,.

Comment: you have to link the sub report to main report with linked id.that may be your primary key or any common field.

Comment: It will be repeated if sub report is placed in detail section...if you don't want to repeat then place in report header

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to not put the subreport in the details section.  You can create a new section that has no automatic iteration in it and just use that.  Or you could put it in the report header or footer.